# Program is not printing textvariable in tkinter label when importing it as a module in another file

Tags: python, module, tkinter, label

I have a file example.py and I want to import it in another file named gsm_call.py. When I an executing example.py separately,its printing 'abcd' in label but when I am importing it as a module, tkinter window open but not printing 'abcd'. Why this is different behavior of a file as a main and as a module. And what is the solution.

example.py

```
`from Tkinter import *
pk=Tk()
var=StringVar()
var.set('abcdd')


label = Label(pk, textvariable=var,font=(25),bg='Orange')
label.place(height=600,width=1370,x=0,y=0)

pk.mainloop()`
```

gsm_call.py

```
`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk



class pk():
        s = ' '


        def printt(self):

            import example


        def __init__(self,master):
            self.new_num = True
            self.s=''
            self.text_box=Entry(master,justify=RIGHT)
            self.text_box.place(height=100,width=1350,x=8,y=0)      

        def num_press(self, num):
                global s
                temp = self.text_box.get()
                temp2 = str(num)     
                if self.new_num:
                     self.current = temp2


                self.current = temp + temp2
                self.display(self.current)
                self.s += str(num)
                self.b=num
        def printlist(self):
                print self.b

        def display(self, value):
                self.text_box.delete(0, END)
                self.text_box.insert(0, value)


class GSM_call(Frame):



    def __init__(self, parent,controller,GSM):
            Frame.__init__(self, parent)
            c =Canvas(self, bg='White', height=700, width=1400,bd=0)
            c.pack()
            global p1       
            p1=pk(self)  

            button1 = Button(self, bd=20,text="1",fg='White',bg="Black",command=lambda : p1.num_press(1))
            button1.place(height=150,width=450,x=10,y=100)


            button2 = Button(self, text="2",bd=20,fg='White',bg="Black",command=lambda: p1.num_press(2))
            button2.place(height=150,width=450,x=460,y=100)

            button3 = Button(self, text="3",bd=20,fg='White',bg="Black",command=lambda: p1.num_press(3))
            button3.place(height=150,width=450,x=910,y=100)

            button4 = Button(self, text="4",bd=20,fg='White',bg="Black",command=lambda: p1.num_press(4))
            button4.place(height=150,width=450,x=10,y=250)

            button5 = Button(self, text="5",bd=20,fg='White',bg="Black",command=lambda: p1.num_press(5))
            button5.place(height=150,width=450,x=460,y=250)

            button6 = Button(self, text="6",bd=20,fg='White',bg="Black",command=lambda: p1.num_press(6))
            button6.place(height=150,width=450,x=910,y=250)

            button7 = Button(self, text="7",bd=20,fg='White',bg="Black",command=lambda: p1.num_press(7))
            button7.place(height=150,width=450,x=10,y=400)

            button8 = Button(self, text="8",bd=20,fg='White',bg="Black",command=lambda: p1.num_press(8))
            button8.place(height=150,width=450,x=460,y=400)

            button9 = Button(self, text="9",bd=20,fg='White',bg="Black",command=lambda: p1.num_press(9))
            button9.place(height=150,width=450,x=910,y=400)

            button0 = Button(self, text="0",bd=20,fg='White',bg="Black",command=lambda: p1.num_press(7))
            button0.place(height=150,width=450,x=460,y=550)

            button_call = Button(self, text="call",bd=20,fg='White',bg="Black",command=lambda: p1.printt())
            button_call.place(height=150,width=450,x=10,y=550)


            button1st = Button(self, text="Back",bd=20,fg='White',bg="Black",
                        command=self.Abc())
            button1st.place(height=150,width=450,x=910,y=550)

def Abc(self):
    #a=lambda: p1.printt()
    print 'a'




if __name__=='__main__':


    ck.mainloop()`
```

example.py using class

```
`from Tkinter import *
pk=Tk()
class Exp():
    def __init__(self,master):

        self.var=StringVar()
        self.var.set('abcdd')


        label = Label(master, textvariable=self.var,font=(25),bg='Orange')
        label.place(height=600,width=1370,x=0,y=0)
par=Exp(pk)

pk.mainloop()`
```

Comment: And you seriously assume we can find out the issue in your code without looking at your code ?

Comment: Where are you importing the other module? And you code does not seem to be complete, what is `ck` ?

Comment: you just imported your package but didn't use anything inside, i would recommend wrap your example in a class, import that class in your gsm_call and create an instance of the class. Also never import *.

Comment: Actually I am using gsm_call.py as a module in other program. Yeah ck=Tk() must be there if i m running gsm_call.py as main. But this is not issue. The problem is that the "import example" imports the example.py when I press button "call" but label in example.py is not printing the textvariable.

Comment: @BigOldTree sir, I have tried even with class in example.py...same thing happened :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have two root windows. A tkinter program must have exactly one root window, and call `mainloop` exactly once <sup>1</sup>. You will need to modify example.py to create an instance of `Toplevel` rather than an instance of `Tk`, and also remove the call to `mainloop` from that file.

---

<sup>1</sup> This isn't literally true, but having more than one is rarely ever a good idea because it creates problems like what you are experiencing.